# Using iOS 8 size class to design different UI for iPad portrait and landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8

I'm trying to design different UI for iPad landscape and portrait mode. Is there any way to implement it using iOS 8 size classes.

Cheers,
Varun Mehta

Answer (score 0):

For iPad both orientations are defined as regular-regular so no, size classes alone can not specify different layouts.